# Scraping data using rvest when "Load more " option is present at the end of the page

Tags: r, web-scraping, screen-scraping, text-mining, rvest

I am learning web scraping and trying to scrape information from https://www.kununu.com/us/google1/reviews.

Here is my code: rm(list=ls())

```
library(httr)
library(rvest)
library(xml2)
library(curl)

url <- "https://www.kununu.com/us/google1/reviews"

reviews <- url %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_nodes(".panel-body")

quote <- reviews %>%
    html_nodes("h2 a") %>%
    html_text()

rating <- reviews %>%
    html_nodes(".tile-heading") %>%
    html_text()

date <- reviews %>%
    html_nodes("strong") %>%
    html_text()

a <- data.frame(quote, rating, date, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

However, the above code scrapes only the first ten bodies. I found in the internet a few suggestions regarding RSelenium package for dynamic websites. Unfortunately, my computer throws error when I use checkForServer(), followed by startServer() commands. Any idea to scrape all the 56 reviews in one go when LOAD MORE option is there at the bottom?

Answer (score 1):

If you hover over the `Load More` link, you'll see that it's just adding an integer to the end of your URL. So just loop over the pages to get them all. First, start with extracting the count of reviews, then get the number of pages that there are, then use your code to get the data...

```
library(httr)
library(rvest)
library(xml2)
library(curl)
library(plyr)

url <- "https://www.kununu.com/us/google1/reviews"
num_of_reviews <- read_html(url) %>%
  html_nodes(".title-number") %>%
  .[[1]] %>%
  html_text()
# round up to nearest 10s
num_of_reviews_rounded <- num_of_reviews %>%
  as.numeric() %>%
  round_any(10, f = ceiling)
pages <- 1 : (num_of_reviews_rounded / 10)

get_reviews <- function(url){
  reviews <- url %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_nodes(".panel-body")

  quote <- reviews %>%
    html_nodes("h2 a") %>%
    html_text()

  rating <- reviews %>%
    html_nodes(".tile-heading") %>%
    html_text()

  date <- reviews %>%
    html_nodes("strong") %>%
    html_text()

  a <- data.frame(quote, rating, date, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  return(a)
}

list_of_dfs <- lapply(pages, function(x)get_reviews(paste0(url, "/", x)))
df <- do.call(rbind, list_of_dfs)

> str(df)
'data.frame':   56 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ quote : chr  "Exceptional: 4.13 of 5" "Noteworthy: 3.75 of 5" "Remarkable: 5.00 of 5" "Exemplary: 4.25 of 5" ...
 $ rating: chr  "\n        4.13\n    " "\n        3.75\n    " "\n        5.00\n    " "\n        4.25\n    " ...
 $ date  : chr  "Dec 30, 2015" "Dec 30, 2015" "Dec 30, 2015" "Dec 29, 2015" ...
```

Comment: Thanks Cory, I will try.